# knockout.js ko.applyBindings() when called from within an object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, frontend, revealing-module-pattern

I'm trying to do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bATu3/5/

Where the entire view is generated within an object, privately and return via a public method so that it can be generated on the page. I'm doing something wrong and would appreciate any pointers to help me sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:http://jsfiddle.net/bATu3/10/

Basically there were few errors: Be careful of the use  of 'this' within callback functions.
Also, note the data bind variables `<p><strong data-bind="text:firstName"></strong></p>`

Comment: I get it, basically i had to limit the scope within the view function to its own instance since the this can be passed to the global instance,
also - since i'm returning the applyBindings into the global scope of the window, i can basically bind it properly.
this is my final take on this problem: http://jsfiddle.net/bATu3/13/ passing the self via applyBindings().

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

another way to do this is: http://jsfiddle.net/bATu3/14/

you can specify the scope for computed values by passing it as a secondary parameter as noted here: [Knockout: Computed Observables](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html) (read the "Managing ‘this’" section)

Comment: that's what i did eventually - jsfiddle.net/bATu3/13

thanks :]